# SQL Server - debugging SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and I am unable to debug the Procedures.

The firewall ports aren't open for Debugging.

I am working on someone else's code and didn't understand this where clause. I didnt even think it was possible

```
WHERE SS_CC.FirstName + SS_CC.LastName + CONVERT(varchar(15),SS_CC.CustomerID) + RF_AS.EventType + SS_CC.AddressLine1 + SS_CC.AddressLine2 + SS_CC.City + SS_CC.[State] + SS_CC.ZipCode +
```

Comment: I think you cut off part of your where clause it ends in +.  Whatever it is doing though it looks very bad just from what you posted.

Comment: actually i copied it exactly the way it was from SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Ok, then it is missing something and is invalid because you can not end a statement with a +.  Or it could be continued on the next line.  Can you post full query

Answer (score 0):

This where clause is missing something at it's right. It could be something like this:

```
WHERE (SS_CC.FirstName + SS_CC.LastName + CONVERT(varchar(15),SS_CC.CustomerID) + RF_AS.EventType + SS_CC.AddressLine1 + SS_CC.AddressLine2 + SS_CC.City + SS_CC.[State] + SS_CC.ZipCode
-- added part
)='something'
```

Comment: Adjusted downvote - but it was because your post did not answer the question (basically restated a few of the comments above).  This would have been more a comment than answer.

Comment: I just thought this will help the person more than comment since formatting is not possible in comment. Thanks @Brad